# How to make proper https request using Finagle to Telegram API

Tags: scala, https, authorization, telegram, finagle

Currently i working at simple bot that will have a telegram interface. The problem is, that finagle have means to make http request, but i have no clue how to make https request.
I tried to make https request with scala-library finagle to telegram bot API:

```
val service: Service[http.Request, http.Response] = Http.client.withTlsWithoutValidation.newService("api.telegram.org:443")
val request = http.Request(http.Method.Get,bottoken + "/getMe")
request.host = "api.telegram.org"
val t  = Await.result(service(request) onSuccess(a => a) onFailure( exc => println("Auth check failed : " + exc.toString )))
if (t.status == Status.Ok) {
  println("Auth check success")
} else {
  println("Auth check failed : " + t.toString + "\r\n" + t.contentString)
}
```

Every time i run this code it yields 400 Bad Request http response.

```
Http.client.withTls("api.telegram.org")
```

yields the same result.
 What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in the Request the http protocol.

```
val request = http.Request(http.Method.Get, "http://yourholeHost/getMe")
```